# Publish app with google maps v2 release key, how to make apk file?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, google-maps-api-2

i'm going crazy with this problem. I have my app with debug api key, all works. I make next

1. Android-tools - Export Signed Application packuage - i have created a new keystore and .apk file
2. C:\Users\Kostya>keytool -list -v -keystore D:\AndroidApps\cars51release\cars51ru_keystore -alias cars51_alias - i get new SHA1 , put it on console and get api key??  Is this a release api key?
   What i must do next? Replace API key in Manifest? How to get reade for publishing apk ?

Answer (score 0):

For release

**1-** Generate SH1 code with the good keystore, good command line

**2-** In google MAP API console click create a new APIKEY copy/paste the SH1 code and then enter the package name (for example : erg46re5g46erg54;com.appli.mainpackage, this is the package name at top of your manifest) it'll generate the APIKEY you need client side

**3-** Copy/Paste the generated APIKEY in your manifest

**4-** Generate signed APK with the same keystore (you can test it on your Nexus4 smartphone X)

**5-** Upload APK on google play

**6-** test

Comment: i have nexus 4) I will try it now, wait a minute please.

Comment: it does not work( if u can wait some time i will show on pictures what i do.

Comment: lol no need for nexus 4 i was just making some pub for google xp What is not working ? Do you get error or warning when lunching your application ?

Comment: i make that you say, and load apk to my phone - it does not work

Comment: Yes i understand that far. But when you say it does not work, explain what do you mean ?

Comment: map is does not loading, display is grey

Comment: ok it's casual issu ^^ check your manifest permissions, and the package name. You should also try to complatly uninstall appli before reloading the APK ... etc

Comment: ohh...now app does not loading map with debug key too. Can you update your ansver with all steps how to publish application for me from the start. i will mark your answer

Comment: To resign APK ? In eclipse right click on the project - android tools - export signed apk ...

Comment: now i put debag key in manifest file and run the app in Eclipse, display is grey

Comment: Yep this mean there is an issu in the communication with google server it's common issu. Note that if you use debug key you don't have to generate an APK :/ Since you changed the key in google map console i assume you copied it in your manifest, you cleaned your project uninstalled the other version of the application in the device and quitted google API console.

Comment: Yes, now i make next 1) Get SHA1 for debug keystore, 2) Put it on google console and create new api key 3) Put api key in my manifest 4) clean project 5) delete old version of my app on phone 6) close google console 7) get grey screen

Comment: Also if the map is blank you should check the logcat in eclipse, there must be warnings and errors (those are the steps, if it is still not working i can't know much if you don't show more code/log)

Comment: Early a get errors in Logcat like "Api key is wrong for this packuage", but now there are no something like this

Answer (score 0):

With the new SHA1 key go to the google developer console and get the release API key. With the new google maps API key, go to your app's manifest file and paste the new api key where required. Export you app again and sign it with the keystore from witch you got the new SHA1 and it should work.

Comment: it does not work( if u can wait some time i will show on pictures what i do.

Comment: How to generate release API key?